# HDD physical health check utility in OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, hardware-failure, diagnostic

Is there a way in OS X to check the the physical health of a HDD;
e.g., if it's been dropped or is displaying signs of wear and tear?

Comment: Like this ?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135565/how-do-i-get-detailed-smart-disk-information-on-os-x-mavericks-or-later

Answer (score 0):

You can get quite a lot of information from the free version of SmartReporter: https://www.corecode.io/smartreporter_lite/

Drop into Utilities and double click it.
Click on icon in bar at top of screen.
Right click on a disk in preferences and play with options.